# Apigility Duvida nos Metódos

Tags: php, zend

Eu estou a usar o **Apigility** para criar **Web Services Rest** só que tenho uma duvida , eu posso acrescentar métodos na class   ***Resource***  , se sim como é que consigo fazer uma chamar o método através do php.

Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Olá, a classe "Resource" no Apigility, tanto Rest como RPC é criada com os métodos que serão chamado pelo controller.

Você normalmente criar métodos dentro da classe e usá-los na própria classe com "$this". Se você pretende chamar estes métodos de outras classes, provavelmente existe algum erro de arquitetura pois a classe resource deve ser usada exclusivamente para responder a um request.

Se quiser detalhar mais seu problema, que tipo de método quer criar, posso ajudar mais.